# How can i filter a 5 minute DataFrame to 15 minutes DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have Bitcoin prices in a csv file. My file is updated every 5 minutes and setting Timestamp as epoc. I have loaded this data to a pandas DataFrame.

What i am trying to do is to convert this data from 5 minutes to 15,30,60, etc. minutes. What i need to do is add x seconds from starting row and read the rest of the file to a DataFrame.

To be clear, I need to get exact data of the timestamp. For example:

```
1006.54999992,1483304400,1006.54999997,1004.00000002,1005.84692623,2686.70823136
1002.69522396,1483305300,1003.50000156,1002.03739724,1003.50000156,1066.56568909
1004.9,1483306200,1004.9,1003.50000155,1003.50000155,4978.96836354
```

Here is the sample data:

```
Close,Timestamp,High,Low,Open,Volume
1006.54999992,1483304400,1006.54999997,1004.00000002,1005.84692623,2686.70823136
1005.40527258,1483304700,1006.54999994,1004.00000001,1006.50831019,11553.13463685
1003.50000156,1483305000,1006.54999994,1002.42767301,1005.40527258,24319.95180383
1002.69522396,1483305300,1003.50000156,1002.03739724,1003.50000156,1066.56568909
1001.97782306,1483305600,1002.69522396,1001.97782306,1002.69522396,2074.17726448
1003.50000155,1483305900,1003.50000155,1001.84692611,1001.84692612,3281.67078015
1004.9,1483306200,1004.9,1003.50000155,1003.50000155,4978.96836354
1006.49999618,1483306500,1006.5499955,1003.50000164,1003.50000347,6070.86273057
1006.99999998,1483306800,1007.0,1004.30668523,1004.30668523,723.41389783
1007.98333891,1483307100,1008.151,1006.54999328,1006.99999999,1357.21576969
1008.23099997,1483307400,1008.54999326,1007.0,1007.0,459.99976456
1005.99999956,1483307700,1008.231,1004.33924087,1007.391,6139.66580632
1007.18578657,1483308000,1007.4,1004.79999999,1005.99999939,11867.90775651
1003.9999994,1483308300,1007.18578594,1001.84692611,1007.18578594,27285.53584028
1001.00000001,1483308600,1003.99999997,1000.2,1003.9999991,11068.8150516
1005.99669899,1483308900,1007.40360648,1001.84692611,1001.84692611,13223.84822808
1004.99999988,1483309200,1005.99669893,1003.00000001,1003.14143239,3069.76051701
1004.00000001,1483309500,1005.99669899,1004.00000001,1004.00000001,616.35942426
1004.99999989,1483309800,1005.99669893,1002.55436881,1003.80404142,1519.48804831
1005.0,1483310100,1006.14142953,1003.05841976,1003.05841976,8158.1735214
1004.99999997,1483310400,1005.0,1004.9999999,1005.0,3497.33824251
1004.99999999,1483310700,1005.0,1002.55399997,1004.99999991,7791.517061
1004.99999969,1483311000,1006.99669898,1004.99999968,1004.99999999,8604.25057064
1005.99999949,1483311300,1007.39313634,1004.99999999,1007.39313634,162.26831131
1004.44444427,1483311600,1005.99999991,1001.84362417,1004.99999999,3803.79028496
1004.99999992,1483311900,1005.99999985,1003.85858574,1003.85858574,69939.19414843
1001.00000001,1483312200,1004.99999993,1001.0,1004.99999992,96461.36606918
```

Comment: Something like `resample`?  You're saying you want any timestamp that falls inbetween 0-15 to be one group, between 15-30, ect... ?

Comment: I am just trying to drop all data between 15 minutes timestamp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with `first`, but for exactly same values is necessary convert all values to `string`s by `dtype=str` in `read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, dtype=str)

df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], unit='s')

df = (df.set_index('Timestamp')
        .resample('15T').first()
        .reset_index()
       .reindex(columns=df.columns))
df['Timestamp'] = df['Timestamp'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9
print (df)
           Close   Timestamp           High            Low           Open  \
0  1006.54999992  1483304400  1006.54999997  1004.00000002  1005.84692623   
1  1002.69522396  1483305300  1003.50000156  1002.03739724  1003.50000156   
2         1004.9  1483306200         1004.9  1003.50000155  1003.50000155   
3  1007.98333891  1483307100       1008.151  1006.54999328  1006.99999999   
4  1007.18578657  1483308000         1007.4  1004.79999999  1005.99999939   
5  1005.99669899  1483308900  1007.40360648  1001.84692611  1001.84692611   
6  1004.99999989  1483309800  1005.99669893  1002.55436881  1003.80404142   
7  1004.99999999  1483310700         1005.0  1002.55399997  1004.99999991   
8  1004.44444427  1483311600  1005.99999991  1001.84362417  1004.99999999   

           Volume  
0   2686.70823136  
1   1066.56568909  
2   4978.96836354  
3   1357.21576969  
4  11867.90775651  
5  13223.84822808  
6   1519.48804831  
7     7791.517061  
8   3803.79028496
```

Comment: in the first example i see same time but different prices values? What i need to do is to get the exact data in every 15,30,60 etc minutes

Comment: @Khun - Can you check now?

Comment: Is this the data i have provided? Because i don't see the values in my data. But let me quickly check it :)

Comment: This code also changes the values. I need to drop all rows between these timestamps

Comment: I mean this code manipulates the values also. Sorry because of my english

Comment: @Khun - There is problem `read_csv` round floats, also [float_precision='high'](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#specifying-method-for-floating-point-conversion) dont help me. So solution is convert all values to `string`s. But then is problem working with them, because not numeric.

Comment: yes this is what i have faced too. So isn't there any way to maybe get data in every x seconds? Maybe applying a lambda to get values every x seconds but i don't know

Comment: Ok and is it possible to get epoc time back in your sample?

Comment: FYI following line fixed the display problem. But now i need to get Timestamp value in timestamp to calculate: pd.set_option('precision', 8)

Comment: @Khun - Not sure if understand, but now I add solution for exactly same output as need.

Comment: Thank you so much. This saved my life :)

Comment: one more thing :) I see time as 1520935500000000000. Added too many zeros at the end

Comment: Do you use `df['Timestamp'] = df['Timestamp'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9` ?

Comment: yes but i have changed the code little bit. I did without converting dataframe to str. So I have actual values and i am trying to convert them

Comment: @Khun - Try add `// 10**9`

Answer (score 2):

It is important to consider the underlying data when deciding how to aggregate it during resampling.

Fundamentally, when moving from 5min granularity to 15min granularity of OHLC data, it is wrong to simply use a standard (*first / last / mean / max*) etc to resample, as that changes the meanings of the columns, and renders them incorrect imo.

I think that we should use .last() for Close, .first() for Open, .max() for high and .min() for Close. We should also sum Volume to get the Volume traded in that 15 min.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Load the DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(file, dtype=str)
# Convert the Timestamp column to the correct format
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], unit='s')
# Index by time to allow us to use .resample()
df.set_index('Timestamp', inplace=True)

# Resample and Aggregate appropriately.
df = (df.resample('15T')
     .agg({'Open': 'first', 'Close': 'last', 
           'High': np.max, 'Low': np.min, 
           'Volume': np.sum})
     )
```

What this is doing is resampling the data to 15 minutes, which necessarily means that there are 3 'ticks' that need to be aggregated per index. We note that to handle the Open we want the First of these, to create a close we want the last Close etc etc.

The .agg() function allows us to pass a Dictionary to it which allows us to pass different aggregation functions to each column.

I think you have to apply this logic to OHLC to downsample it accurately.

Comment: Great point! What i actually do is to get min max open close but doing it long way. This way seems better to be honest. Thank you so much